# when displaying buttons the sheet behind is not clickable

Tags: excel, vba, button, userform, floating

I am using a code below to display my "macro buttons" in Excel. Once they appear on the screen they work fine but the sheet behind them isn't clickable which prevents some of my macros that involve moving around the sheet from working. Please help!

```
Sub ShowButtons()

Buttons.Show

End Sub
```

Comment: Are these "buttons" on a userform?

Comment: read this, might be helpful: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251540.aspx

Comment: Would also recommend avoiding `Select` as it will continue to cause you headaches...like here.

Answer (score -1):

You need to make it modeless by adding 0.

```
Sub ShowButtons()

    Buttons.Show 0

End Sub
```

But since you need to interact with the sheet, maybe your buttons should be **on** the sheet itself instead of on a userform?

EDIT: just rememberd that it's supposed to be 0 and not 1.